# Python: Looping through part of a list to find prime numbers

Tags: python

First I am meant to construct a list including the prime number 2. 
Then I am supposed to loop through the numbers 3 to about 10000, check whether each number is divisible by each element in the list, for all elements equal to or less than the square root of n. 
If not, then add that number to the list.
So far I have:

```
from math import sqrt

primes = [2]

for n in xrange(3,10000):
    if all(n % p for p in primes):
       primes.append(n)
    else:
        continue

print primes
```

I am unsure how to get the looping through primes to stop when an element <= sqrt(n) is reached.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) from `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> n, primes = 11, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
>>> all(n % p for p in takewhile(lambda p: p * p < n + 1, primes))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

To exit a loop you can use the `break` keyword eg:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for value in list:
  if value == 5:
    break
  print(value)
```

Would give you:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt 
from math import ceil #takes the ceiling of a number there is also floor instead

primes = [2]

for n in xrange(3,int(ceil(sqrt(10000)))): #take the int of the ceiling of square root 
    if all(n % p for p in primes): 
        primes.append(n) 
    else: 
        continue

print primes
```

Is that what you're looking for?